# Gmail to Google Spread Sheet (only date, email and subject)

Tags: gmail

The code I have cobbled together does work, but it imports the wrong things from my email. I only want the date sent, the sender email address and the subject to import into the google sheet.

Can anyone help?

```html
function onOpen() {
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    let menuItems = [
        {name: 'Gather emails', functionName: 'gather'},
    ];
    spreadsheet.addMenu('SP LEGALS', menuItems);
}
      function gather() {
    let messages = getGmail();

    let curSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

    messages.forEach(message => {curSheet.appendRow(parseEmail(message))});
}
   function getGmail() {
      const query = "to:legals@salisburypost.com";

    let threads = GmailApp.search(query,0,10);

    let messages = [];

    threads.forEach(thread => {
        messages.push(thread.getMessages()[0].getPlainBody());
        label.addToThread(thread);
    });

    return messages;
}

function parseEmail(message){
    let parsed = message.replace(/,/g,'')
        .replace(/\n*.+:/g,',')
        .replace(/^,/,'')
        .replace(/\n/g,'')
        .split(',');

    let result = [0,1,2,3,4,6].map(index => parsed[index]);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the detail information of `it imports the wrong things from my email.`?

Comment: yes, it brings in parts of the body of the email. I really only need the date, sender and subject to import into the google sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike - That WORKED, thank you so very much. Is there a way to have it skip emails it has already imported? Or maybe label ones imported as READ, and only import UNREAD emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve "the date, sender and subject" from the 1st message in the searched threads to the active sheet of Google Spreadsheet.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In this case, you can retrieve "the date, sender and subject" using the built-in methods for GmailApp.
- When the values are put to the Spreadsheet, when `appendRow` is used in the loop, the process cost will become high.
- It seems that `label` is not declared in your script.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this modification, I modified `gather()` and `getGmail()` for achieving your goal.

```
function gather() {
  let messages = getGmail();
  if (messages.length > 0) {
    let curSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    curSheet.getRange(curSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, messages.length, messages[0].length).setValues(messages);
  }
}

function getGmail() {
  const query = "to:legals@salisburypost.com";
  let threads = GmailApp.search(query,0,10);
  let messages = [];
  threads.forEach(thread => {
    const m = thread.getMessages()[0];
    messages.push([m.getDate(), m.getFrom(), m.getSubject()]);
//    label.addToThread(thread);
  });
  return messages;
}
```

- When no threads are retrieved with `"to:legals@salisburypost.com"`, the values are not put to the Spreadsheet. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [getDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getdate)
- [getFrom()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getfrom)
- [getSubject()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getsubject)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)